# In Flutter, how to manage the number of screen instances?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-routes

I noticed when I ran the navigator observer that I'm building a huge stack of opened screens when I keep navigating between two screens. I researched the topic and the resources available aren't enough. I'm usually using pushnamed in my app unless the screen is one time use only at that time I just pop it or user popAndPushNamed. I tried to use pushNamedAndRemoveUntil but it removes more screens that it supposed to which causes to navigate to an empty route in some widgets. What I'm trying to achieve is having only a single instance of each screen built in the app and navigate between them without building a stack of the same screens!

Comment: Try this: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route

Comment: Thanks! Well appreciated! I checked the documents it looks promising! I'll test it today Inshallah